# Can not access web app on the network running kubernetes and minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have a docker container which runs a basic front end angular app. I have verified it runs with no issues and I can successfully access the web app in the browser with `docker run -p 5901:80 formbuilder-stand-alone-form`.

I am able to successfully deploy it with minikube and kubernetes on my cloud dev server

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: stand-alone-service

spec:
  selector:        
    app: stand-alone-form
  
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5901
      targetPort: 80
  
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: stand-alone-form-app
  labels:               
    app: stand-alone-form
spec:                   
  replicas: 1           
  
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: stand-alone-form

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: stand-alone-form
    
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: stand-alone-form-pod
        image: formbuilder-stand-alone-form
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:                
        - containerPort: 80
```

```
one@work ...github/stand-alone-form-builder-hhh/form-builder-hhh (main)
% kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
stand-alone-form-app-6d4669f569-vsffc   1/1     Running   0          6s
one@work ...github/stand-alone-form-builder-hhh/form-builder-hhh (main)
% kubectl get deployments
NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
stand-alone-form-app   1/1     1            1           8s
one@work ...github/stand-alone-form-builder-hhh/form-builder-hhh (main)
% kubectl get services   
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          5d7h
stand-alone-service   LoadBalancer   10.96.197.197   <pending>     5901:30443/TCP   21s
```

However, I am not able to access it with the url:

```
one@work ...github/stand-alone-form-builder-hhh/form-builder-hhh
%  minikube service stand-alone-service 
|-----------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |        NAME         | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | stand-alone-service |        5901 | http://192.168.49.2:30443 |
|-----------|---------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
```

In this example, `http://192.168.49.2:30443/` gives me a dead web page.

I disabled all my iptables for troubleshooting.

Any idea how to access the front end web app? I was thinking I might have the selectors wrong but sure.

**UPDATE**: Here is the requested new outputs:

```
one@work ...github/stand-alone-form-builder-hhh/form-builder-hhh (main)
% kubectl describe service stand-alone-service
Name:                     stand-alone-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=stand-alone-form
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.96.197.197
IPs:                      10.96.197.197
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.96.197.197
Port:                     <unset>  5901/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30443/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.2:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

```
one@work ...github/stand-alone-form-builder-hhh/form-builder-hhh (main)
% minikube tunnel
Password: 
Status: 
    machine: minikube
    pid: 237498
    route: 10.96.0.0/12 -> 192.168.49.2
    minikube: Running
    services: [stand-alone-service]
    errors: 
        minikube: no errors
        router: no errors
        loadbalancer emulator: no errors
```

**Note**: I noticed with the tunnel I do have a external IP for the loadbalancer now:

```
one@work ...github/stand-alone-form-builder-hhh/form-builder-hhh (main)
% kubectl get service   
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>          443/TCP          5d11h
stand-alone-service   LoadBalancer   10.98.162.179   10.98.162.179   5901:31596/TCP   3m10s
```

Comment: The Service wiring looks correct to be, but to double-check, can you `kubectl describe service stand-alone-service`?  In particular at the end you should see a line that says `Endpoints:`, and it should not say "none".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your LoadBalancer hasn't quite resolved correctly, as the External-IP is still marked as `<pending>`

According to Minikube, this happens when the tunnel is missing:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#check-external-ip

Have you tried running `minikube tunnel` in a separate command window?

- https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel
- https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/

Comment: Great idea. I tried it... but still not having success and getting the dead web page. I updated the post with the output from the command

Comment: Just wanted to mention... with the tunnel running I do see a ip address now for load balancer instead of pending. Still can not access my web app though. I tried using the external ip but still no luck

Comment: Interesting, yeah I'd expect you to be able to get to the service on `192.168.49.2:5901` with the tunnel running. 
Can you define what you mean when you say "getting the dead web page", do you have the cURL results of this perhaps?

Comment: % curl http://192.168.49.2:31073/ results in 

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 31073: Connection refused

Comment: I tried this on my google cloud and it worked! I think there is something about my KVM server and kvm guest (both linux and using linux bridge on host) that is disagreeing with minikube networking.

Comment: Glad it's working for you where it needs to, not too sure what the underlying issue could be there. Did you have the ingress addon enabled on your Minikube cluster? (It doesn't need it, just wondering if it's worth looking at in regards to interference

Comment: well.... not sure. It's 2 different issues actually. The load balancer won't work on my kvm host and guest. But as far as using external IP with minikube's tunnel... that won't work on google cloud ether.